Grinding 1st gear
Mercedes E300de Auto 2013.
My Mercedes grinds and sometimes has difficulty engaging 1st gear. Is it possible to bypass 1st gear?

Are you able to engage 2nd gear from a standstill? I would expect the grinding in 1st is due to a clutch not properly disengaging the engine from the transmission, which would also apply to any other gear. If you are able to engage 2nd gear from a standstill, you may be able to begin to move, but expect accelerated clutch wear and reduced acceleration from a dead stop.

The car is Automatic so I wouldn't know how to engage 2nd gear without going through 1st gear

That sounds like big trouble. Older automobiles with automatic transmissions had an option of "manual" selection of 1, 2, D which might have been of some value. Keep in mind that the internal components of the transmission are used in all gear selections in some combination and your transmission is probably self-destructing.
